# anchor tag helper auto add area to link in area view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0

```
  <a asp-action="Logout" asp-controller="Account" > logout</a>
```

in home page not problem , link look like /account/logout
but inside User Area Page link look like   /user/account/logout
and error NotFound

this my map route

```
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
               name: "areas",
               pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("defualt", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Comment: I will not get your actual problem, It's kind of redirect issue use - RedirectToAction

Comment: Kindly try to explain properly as you are not at all clear . Try like this what’s the input and what You need as output .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit anchor  like  this

```
 <a asp-action="Logout" asp-controller="Account" asp-area="" > logout</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be by design that the link without the `asp-area` in area view will add the areaname to the url.`Area Name` is used to indicate where to find the Controller. eg, if you follow [Areas in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.0), it will have multiple different `HomeController` in dfferent `Area`. Without area name, it will not able to redirect to the specific Controller with `Home/Index`.

If you want to redirect from Area to root controller , you could use the following in the area page:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Logout","Account", new { area="" })">logout</a>
```

Or you should add the corresponding view and controller under User area like below :
[image]